# Can I send an integer in binary form over the network without having to fear UB from trap values?

Tags: c, posix, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

Frankly, is such a code valid (aside for the lack of necessary error checking, omitted here for simplicity)?

Code to send data over the Internet:

```
uint16_t i = htons(500);

sendto(sockfd, &i, sizeof(uint16_t), 0, &dest_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
```

Code to receive this data:

```
uint16_t i;
recvfrom(sockfd, &i, sizeof(uint16_t), 0, src_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
i = ntohs(i);
if(i < 100 || i > 1000)
    fprintf(stderr, "Received invalid data over the network\n");
else
    do_something(i);
```

My concern is, that since I read that the C standard allows trap value for any type other than `unsigned char`, is it possible that this way I might receive such a trap value over the network, and thus I’ll have UB as soon as I write `i = ntohs(i)`?

Or does POSIX guarantee that `uint16_t` and `uint32_t` shall not have trap values?

Or is it not guaranteed by any official standard, however the vast majority of implementations do not have trap values for `uint16_t` and `uint32_t`, and thus as per this de-facto standard I don’t have to fear this?

Comment: The pigeonhole principle guarantees no trap values in a uint16_t.

Comment: Curious that there is a concern over trap values (rare), yet code snippet does not check the return values of `sendto()` and `recvfrom()` - a more common short-coming.

Comment: @chux I am aware this is to be checked, I just thought checking this doesn’t belong to this question, so I’ve omitted it for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: @gaazkam Endian is not an issue for the core of this problem either.  Yet since the code included `htons()`, etc. it seems like more than just the most simply code and hence the query about checking return values.  Recall others, not as skilled as yourself, see these code snippets and run with them.  Still a good question.  BTW: does not POSIX offer `htobe16()` instead of  `htons()`?

Comment: @chux Thank you for telling me about `htobe16()`, I used `htons()` simply because on my academic course they told me about `htons()`, not `htobe16()`, and I didn’t even know such a function as `htobe16` exists :) From what I read in `man 3 endian`, the `htobe16()` function, as well as a family of similar functions are non-standard, while `htons` and a family of similar functions are mandated by POSIX (`man 3 byteorder`).

Answer (score 1):

C99 specifies that the fixed width types must be two's complement and have no padding bits. The bit of the standard that talks about trap representations says that in integer types only padding bits can cause trap representations. So we don't even need to dig into POSIX to see that your code is fine.

POSIX additionally makes all integer types two's complement (I can't find this now, either it says so explicitly or it's a consequence of certain other things in POSIX, I don't remember).

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is "yes". What you're doing is fine.

The bit I think you're worried about is this:

> Certain object representations need not represent a value of the object type. If the stored
>   value of an object has such a representation and is read by an lvalue expression that does
>   not have character type, the behavior is undefined.

For uinxx_t I don't believe there are any trap values. All combinations of bit values produce a valid number (i.e. object representation). I.e., all bit combinations "represent a value of the object type", therefore you cannot initialise a uintxx_t to a trap value/representation.

The standard then goes onto say, which I'd never read before, so this was quite interesting:

> For signed integer types ...If the sign bit is one, the value shall be
>   modified in one of the following ways:
>
> — the corresponding value with
>   sign bit 0 is negated (sign and magnitude);
>
> — the sign bit has the
>   value -(2N) (two’s complement);
>
> — the sign bit has the value -(2N - 1)
>   (one’s complement).
>
> Which of these applies is implementation-defined,
>   as is whether the value with sign bit 1 and all value bits zero (for
>   the first two), or with sign bit and all value bits 1 (for one’s
>   complement), is a trap representation or a normal value.

So, it might be a problem if you were using *signed* integers, but it does not appear to be for *un*signed integers.

Answer (score 0):

`uint16_t` cannot have trap values in memory - there are 16 value bits with no padding bits. However, an uninitialized local variable, whose address has never been taken, will have an indeterminate value. As the address of `i` is taken here, it must reside in memory and even if `recvfrom` fails it will have a valid unspecified value.

Comment: Why did you take you're error checking comment out? I thought is was a good point :)

Comment: @Jimbo because I noticed I was lying there :D

Comment: Ah... I didn't spot the lie, what was it? :)

Comment: The statement "even if `recvfrom` fails, `i` will have a valid unspecified value" relies on an interpretation of the C rules about indeterminate values which is probably not what the C committee intended, and _definitely_ not what C compilers implement. In this case you can probably get away with it because the compiler probably doesn't know the semantics of `recvfrom`, but in general, reading an uninitialized variable provokes full-fledged UB treatment from the compiler even if it's impossible for that variable to have trap representations (for whatever reason).

Comment: @zwol: The Standard makes an explicit distinction between automatic variables that have their address taken and those that do not; it also makes clear that the distinction is based upon the *presence* of code which takes the variable's address, rather than the *execution* of code that uses the resulting pointer to access it.

Comment: @supercat Yes, I know, but I'm not aware of any compiler (even among those that claim C11 conformance) that implements that rule as written, and if you asked implementors I fully expect their reaction would first be "What, seriously?!" and then "That's a defect and we are going to continue ignoring it."  The semantic everyone actually implements is to pretend J.2 "The behavior is undefined [if] the value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is indeterminate" is normative.

Comment: @zwol: It would be good and useful for gcc to offer modes which offer no pretext of being standards-conforming, but would offer useful optimizations for some kinds of programs.  If the Standard defines a behavior, however, a compiler writer who says "that's stupid" and ignores it, *but still claims to be standard-conforming*, should be branded as a liar.

Comment: @supercat This not one of your hobby-horse cases where naive code generation used to do something useful. This is something that really will blow up in your face even with naive code generation, it's a consistent interpretation over _all_ compilers going back _decades_, and it's also almost certainly what the committee thought they were specifying.

Comment: @zwol: Many compilers will often store smaller variable types using longer registers, and mask off the upper bits when they are written.  I would regard as plausible the notion that a compiler that notices that a variable's address is only used within certain parts of a function might optimize that variable to a register elsewhere, and if execution doesn't reach that code the variable might behave as though it holds a value outside the range for its type.  The Standard doesn't define any means by which a variable can behave as though it holds a value outside its type's range *except* UB, ...

Comment: ...but in cases where a value will sometimes be used and sometimes ignored, and will sometimes be meaningful and sometimes not, optimization will not be enhanced by requiring programmers to explicitly set values which are going to be ignored anyway.  Further, I suspect a major factor in the change is that a fair amount of code may have relied upon the fact that given `uint16_t foo; someFunction(&foo);`, the value of `foo` would behave like a number read from RAM--something that would certainly happen in the absence of cross-function optimization.  While it...

Comment: ...might have been possible and even useful to describe in detail cases where function boundaries must be regarded as significant, I don't see a whole lot of genuinely-useful optimization opportunities that would need to be foregone to uphold the Standard's requirements.  What cases where vintage compilers would anything weird in cases where a value ends up being ultimately ignored, or where conforming this part of the Standard would be difficult or expensive?

Comment: @supercat You're doing your thing again, where you ramble on about your hypothetical language that you believe should be what C is specified to be, and I'm just not interested. When I'm talking about C on this site I am _only_ interested in explaining what actual compilers actually do and how that relates to the actual text of the actual standard.  In this case it's really very simple: J.2 contains a bald statement that reading uninitialized variables is UB. Every implementor since the beginning of time has treated that as normative, even though technically it isn't.

Comment: @supercat Moreover, there is good reason, from the text of the standard, to believe that the committee _thought_ the normative text did make that requirement; for instance, the text assumes repeatedly that _any_ access to an indeterminate value provokes UB, without considering the possibility of trap representations or addresses having been taken. It is only when you close-read the definition of "indeterminate value" that you realize that there's a loophole.

Comment: @supercat Now, the addition in C11 of a sentence to 6.3.2.1p2 that _could have_ said "If the lvalue designates an object whose value is indeterminate, the behavior is undefined, even if the object's type has no trap representations", but instead says something much more complicated and limited, does argue for your position. However, I strongly suspect that the C committee thought they were patching a related but distinct defect and (still) didn't realize the loophole due to the definition of "indeterminate value" even exists.

Comment: @supercat See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#240 and http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#616 (for C++ but the discussion of the C committee's parallel thinking is instructive).

Comment: @zwol: If all accesses to Indeterminate Value invoke UB, then why does N1570 3.19.2 define Indeterminate Value as "either an unspecified value or a trap representation"?  I agree that the semantics associated with Indeterminate Value should give more freedom than what the above would imply, but that doesn't mean that every use of Indeterminate Value should jump the rails.  I'm also still curious what whacky things vintage compilers did with indeterminate values on systems without trap representations, and what glorious optimizations are impeded by saying compilers have to stay on the rails.

Comment: @zwol: Consider also that some data structures would benefit greatly from a guarantee that reading a `uint16_t` or a `uint32_t` from an array will yield a number of that type with no other side-effect, even if the element holds Indeterminate Value.  If there were Standard-defined intrinsics which said "Set an object (or range of objects) of a type with no trap representations to Unspecified Value", which compilers could process by blocking certain optimizations but not generating code, then it might make sense to require that code implementing such data structures...

Comment: ...must initialize them with such intrinsics before use.  As it is, though, by what means could the authors of the Standard intend that code which would work just fine with any bit pattern an object might hold, could guarantee that accessing the object would yield behavior consistent with it holding some arbitrary bit pattern?  If code needs to e.g. create a hash table that might be called upon to hold a million elements, but would usually hold far fewer before it is abandoned and the storage is recycled, having to actually clear all the elements could be a big performance drain.

Comment: @supercat Again, in this context I am not interested in discussing whether the standard and the implementations _should be_ the way they are.  I am only interested in providing accurate factual information about what the standard says, what implementations do, and the extent to which they are in concord.  And I already did that, so I won't be responding any more.

Comment: @zwol: The text of the Standard clearly and unambiguously indicates that the rule would would generally allow reads of an uninitialized automatic to invoke Undefined Behavior is inapplicable in the presence of code that takes the variable's address.  You seem to find that unreasonable, and I'm trying to understand why.

Comment: @zwol: I meant that the Standard limits that the rule *that* would generally make such reads UB is inapplicable if a variable's address is taken.  Also, I think the intention of the Standard is that structures may be fully examined and copied using character-types pointers without invoking UB, even if they have not been fully written.  The ARM version of gcc on godbolt doesn't seem to be conforming in that regard, but maybe newer versions fix that?

Answer (score -2):

You also need to consider endian-ness of client and server while sending and receiving binary data.

If your client is little endian and sending to big endian server, at server you dont need to convert binary data back if client had already converted it to network byte order

Comment: the code was explicitly converting the data to network byte order.

Comment: I am trying to mention that, if we consider client running on a platform that is little endian and server on big endian
Client sends integer value 1, in network byte ordering 4 bytes will be sent as 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01
Server picks it in its integer variable, if server is big endian, it already got value 1 correctly represented in memory as 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01
Now if the code calls ntohs, it will just reverse the byte ordering makeing it 0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00, thus changing the value altogether
My suggestion is to call ntohs/htons after verifying endianess of client and server

Comment: @Pras On a big-endian architecture, `ntohs`, `htons`, `ntohl`, and `htonl` will all be no-ops.

Comment: true, in arpa/inet.h on big endian system I see them defined as 
#define htonl(x) ((in_addr_t)(x))
#define htons(x) ((in_port_t)(x))
#define ntohl(x) ((in_addr_t)(x))
#define ntohs(x) ((in_port_t)(x))
no-ops as you mentioned